# How to find the snippet of JavaScript that modifies an element?

Tags: javascript, dom, firebug, element

The page I'm trying inspect has a hidden `<input type="hidden" name="Foo" value="123 />` element on a page, where Javascript/AJAX modifies the value. I'm trying to find where on earth in Javascript is the code that modifies this value from time to time.

Is there a tool that could help me find the places in javascript that use/modify that element? Does Firebug provide this, if so, how?

Note: If tried looking for "Foo" in the code, but I haven't found any matching titles. There's JSON and Mootools loaded, +application specific code, which results several thousands lines of code. The element is probably accessed indirectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that the javascript is modifying this value? Since it looks you already know when it's called (since you know it changes), I would suggest a breakpoint in Firebug in the first event that initiates the changing (probably an onclick attribute in other element).

It's kind of hard telling you a "generic" way of knowing where in javascript it's changing Foo's value since there are a lot of different approachs, different libraries, each one with it's syntax.

For example, if you tried searching "Foo" and didn't find it, the script may be traversing the DOM and changing the input's value as a "first child of something". I would try to search for names or ids of input's parent elements and understand the code from there.

I usually just try to understand the javascript logic from every script I use with Firebug's debugging techniques - but just on the script that uses the libraries.

Comment: +1 for the generic way of 'grep'ing the source for candidates making the change. Hopefully there should be better ways to set a breakpoint than this as described in other answers.

Answer (score 8):

Firebug 1.5 will have "Break-on-Modify" on the HTML panel. See http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html#html - Break on DOM (HTML) Mutation Events.

Comment: +1 for the info. There does exist a break-on-modify feature of setting breakpoints. However when I did try to set such a breakpoint it did not work i.e. it did not break on the code making the changes to say a button title/state getting changed. So not sure what needs to be done apart from setting the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If Firebug doesn't let you define breakpoints on setting some value, you could insert something like this in the page (Firefox-only):

```
$("textarea")[0].__defineSetter__("value", function(val) {
   alert("called");
})
```

And either breakpoint on the function in Firebug or use `console.log` or whatever to dump the stack to the firebug console.

I remember seeing somewhere a presentation on Firebug plans, which included a section on various kinds of breakpoints to be supported, but I can't find a link to it right now.

---

[edit] The above is for the case the value is set by assigning to the value property: `.value = ...`. If you need to catch the moment an *attribute* is changed (`.setAttribute("value", ...)`), you can use DOM mutation listeners.

Comment: +1 for the info. Can you share info on __how__ to use DOM mutation listeners? A link or two perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: @GuruM: use addEventListener with the event name DOMAttrModified, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events . Note that mutation listeners are being phased out in favor of a different mechanism, mutation observers (also mentioned on that MDN page)